# Оптимизация кода: создание "универсального" метода действия в контроллере

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, инспекция-кода

Есть следующая иерархия классов

```
public abstract class OperationItemViewModel
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public int OperationId {get;set;}
    public int OperationItemTypeId {get; protected set;}
    //Прочие свойства
}

public class ProgramViewModel : OperationItemViewModel
{
    public ProgramViewModel() { this.OperationItemTypeId = 6;}       
}

public class SetupMapViewModel : OperationItemViewModel
{
    public SetupMapViewModel() { this.OperationItemTypeId = 3;}       
}
```

и следующий контроллер

```
public class OperationController: Controler
{
    public ActionResult AddProgram(int operationId){}

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddProgram(ProgramViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase downloadableFile)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _operationService.AddItem(model);
        }
    }

    public ActionResult AddSetupMap(int operationId){}

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddSetupMap(SetupMapViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase downloadableFile)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _operationService.AddItem(model);
        }
    }
}
```

сигнатура метода `AddItem` выглядит так:

```
public void AddItem<T>(T item) where T: OperationItemViewModel
{
    var operationItem = //преобразовываем `ViewModel` в `DAO`
    _context.Set<OperationItem>().Add(operationItem);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

в приведенном мной случае все работает но не нравится что методы Add(*Program/SetupMap/...*) в большей степени *копипаста*.

Можно ли как то *оптимизировать* данный код - т.е. избавиться от дублирования внутри методов?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Вариант 1.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddProgram(ProgramViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase downloadableFile) => Add(model, downloadableFile);
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddSetupMap(SetupMapViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase downloadableFile) => Add(model, downloadableFile);

private ActionResult Add(OperationItemViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase downloadableFile) 
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _operationService.AddItem(model);
    }
}
```

### Вариант 2

Снимаем с `OperationItemViewModel` абстрактность и убираем иерархию.

### Вариант 3.

Можно что-нибудь придумать с ModelBinder:

```
class OperationItemModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(OperationItemViewModel))
        {
            var realType = /* как-нибудь вычислить */;
            bindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, realType );
        }

        return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
    }
}

[ModelBinder(typeof(OperationItemModelBinder))]
public abstract class OperationItemViewModel
{
    // ...
}
```